# Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS : Simple Navigation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

This is really basic. But I have no idea where I am going wrong.

I am on the ARC mode and all I have done is written the following code in my AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions function

    homePage *hp = [[homePage alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hp];
```

The home page gets loaded up correctly and there is a button on the homePage which when clicked should trigger a pressedPlay: wired up correctly in the .xib. But as soon as the button is clicked the program crashes with the error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any help please?

Comment: What is after this code, what are you doing with the `navcon` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix to the problem. With ARC the view to be pushed into the navigation controller must have a strong property associated with it, otherwise it is released.

Answer (score 1):

This usually means something had a reference count of zero and then you tried to use it.

I bet it is something to do with whatever your button touch event is trying to process.  Step through the code and see exactly at what point the crash happens.

Comment: @EIJay : I stepped through the code and I can’t get anything. The View loads up fine because I had a breakpoint in viewDidLoad and I successfully go ahead. And now when I click the button it simply crashes. Doesn’t execute any code.

Comment: Can you zip up the project, stick it in your public dropbox folder and send me the link?  eljaywilson_AT_gmail_DOT_com

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
homePage *hp = [[homePage alloc] initWithNibName:@"homePage" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hp];
```

And follow naming conventions instead of `homePage` it should be `HomePage`.

Comment: Doesn’t work!  I now get the error: [__NSCFString pressedPlay]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: now you are getting exception..not `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.. this exception shows that your are calling `pressedPlay` on a `NSString` object.

Comment: I just tried removing ARC and it works. But with ARC the same error.